# Possibility of non-magical superpowers

Tags: science-based, super-powers

I am not writing a story, this just came to me as an idea. How can one introduce superpowers in his world without an appeal to magic or heavy machinery (in fact, without an appeal to machinery which is visible at all)? In some sense, you won't be able to say "look, he has superpowers" unless the targeted person manifests it.

Comment: This sounds like a similar situation to the "6 million dollar man". No heavy machinery or magic, just high tech.

Comment: This question would be improved if you specifically defined what "superpowers" is/are.  X-ray vision?  Strength? Speed? Cause Bad Weather? Kill with a Touch? Wealth (Batman, you know...).  So many things have been called "superpowers" over the years that this question is too broad without a specific definition.  Ideally, pick one and only one superpower to mimic without magic or heavy machinery.

Comment: Well, Marvel/DC universes have only _some_ magic involved. Most of the time there is some kind of "scientific" explanation of superpowers.

Comment: Highly related: my answer to [What's the smallest change to physics required to allow magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40949/whats-the-smallest-change-to-physics-required-to-allow-magic/40992#40992)

Comment: Jon Connor in the film [Terminator Genysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_Genisys) would seem to fit, but the question could be better if the terms were defined. For example - the ability to ignore emotional/social rejection without feeling anything (ie. psychopathy/sociopathy) would count as a superpower by the terms of your question.

Comment: @Alexander most Marvel/DC powers are so handwavy, they might as well be magic.

Comment: @Nosajimiki - they might - or they might not. So the question becomes "how much hard science do we want?"

Comment: Depending on your definition of superpowers, some people already have them with no technological or magical (obviously) assistance. For example some people can see into the UV or do not feel pain (though admittedly this is only beneficial in fiction, and in reality is very dangerous.)

Comment: I agree that this question lacked specificity, however, I like Halfthawed's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it depends on how you define 'magic' and 'heavy machinery'. And 'superpowers', for that matter. Superpowers, plainly put, are powers that are *impossible* for a normal human to have. Strength beyond that of a human, flight, speed, etc. In other words, a power that a human can't have without outside aid. It's impossible to have them without the addition of some kind of gimmick to give it to them, which is usually magic or heavy machinery. Take the X-Men, for instance. Some have identifiable mutations (Angel, Beast, etc.) but others are perfectly normal until they use their powers (Iceman, Jean Grey, etc.). Does this qualify as 'magic'? Well, Marvel says it doesn't, because magic in Marvel is clearly defined (Dr. Strange, for instance) and X-Men powers comes from radiation mutated genes, retconned into junk DNA introns, retconned into mutant DNA, but not from radiation. But there's nothing in DNA that would explain the powers, is there?

So if you want to label something as 'not-magic' and explain that's not what's happening, you can do that. But if you want to say that the main characters have unexplainable powers that no one else has without a fantastic explanation? Well, then it's just not a superpower. It's a normal power. Guns, for instance, would be considered a superpower (in the heavy machinery sense) in the 11th century, but a normal one in the 21st. So if you want a legitimate superpower, an ability which is beyond the reach of normal humans, but you want an explanation for how said human has it without resorting to phlebotinum, handwavium, or unexistium? Not possible.

Answer (score 6):

We have historical examples of these occurrence; just to quote some of them:

- when the first European explorers visited the Americas on their horses, the local people took them for divine creatures, hybrid of men and horses, which were unknown to them.
- when the first guns were used against the Polynesian people or other less advanced civilization, a stick which emitted a puff of white smoke and the sound of thunder leaving you dead at a distance was surely perceived as a superpower.
- the [cargo cults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) developed in the Pacific, when the indigenous saw the cargo delivering goods during WWII, just a consequence of a man waving some sticks in the air.

To wrap up, remember the well known statement:

> Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

Comment: @AlexP, removed that part

Answer (score 1):

Wolverine style regeneration can probably be implemented with nanites which at our current technology level might as well be magic.

Small scale drones with wifi cameras and microphones could be used to implement super sight, claravoyance and distance-hearing.

Super strength could probably be accomplished through xenografting.  There are a number of animals whose muscles have a much higher strength-to-weight ratio than humans.  Some of them are pretty close to us genetically.  Current technology, animal-rights-groups and rejection issues might present a problem but it's closer-to-real than the nanites.

Extraordinary skill at reading body language when mixed with intuition and good social media hacking skills might pass for mind reading.

Incredible wealth is functionally equivalent to mind control.  There are very few who will disobey you if you compensate them super-generously.

Comment: Global mind control = propaganda. Buy all the big media company, Hollywood, etc. Or those megacorps behind them to sell a certain idea as cool.