# How would magic work?

Tags: science-based, magic

So sorry about all the other ways I phrased this question. So I am writing a world where there is lots of magic, but the magic is actually a kind of science that our world(the real world) just hasn't understood yet. This new science is used in many ways. I have no idea how the magic will work. The key features that the magic can do are: levitate someone, change their shape, and lets them control the five basic elements of life(in their culture): Earth, Air, Fire, Water, and Blood.  I really want a way to this new science/ technology to be somehow controlled by the different races and cultures. Again, sorry for the bad phrasing of the other two revisions.

Comment: This question feels too broad at the moment. Perhaps ask about a specific type of "magic" you want and then we can explore that but right now answers can be about anything from telepathy and teleportation to summoning demons from the abyss.

Comment: You have to care if you want your question to stay open here. People might spend a lot of time and effort answering your question and then at the end you decide this wasn't the direction you wanted to go in and all was wasted. It's also 1 question per topic. Btw, could you give us a good definition of what would be "magic" in contrast to "a conventional device that makes things levitate like rotor blades of a helicopter already do" and many other things commonly (but of course incorrectly, magic would be technology  by definition of the word technology) called "technology"

Comment: The question is worded in such a way that I’m led to believe that you want us to create your magic system for you. That isn’t the purpose of this stackexchange. Work on your magic system more and come back later if you run into bumps along the way. Questions should be clearly be questions. This almost feels more like a writing prompt.

Comment: A couple of related questions: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22591/can-magic-be-or-directly-work-as-science; https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40949/whats-the-smallest-change-to-physics-required-to-allow-magic. I think this is a duplicate of the first listed. You can use the search feature to check out questions already posted on this site. I searched for 'magic science' and go a lot of relevant questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can magic BE or directly work as science?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22591/can-magic-be-or-directly-work-as-science)

Comment: It is a duplicate if some other questions. Sorry. I'm new here.

Comment: "Science-based" and "Magic" are incompatible by definition. You've deliberately picked two opposite things and asked us to make them the same for you. Pick one or the other.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you may have noticed, the community is rather picky about [tag:magic] questions. We are happy to help fine-tune your magic system, identify flaws or weak points in it, exploit it, or use it within its own constraints, but creating your magic system isn't something we do. There are simply too many valid solutions to be able to objectively rate one as better than another. Spend some time with your magic system; if you have questions later, feel free to ask them. If you haven't already, feel free to take the [tour] to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: Read Rick Cook's Wiz Biz - it might give you ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you understand magic, it aint magic. It's science.

If the universe is a giant computer simulation, magicians would be people who find exploits or have elevated user permissions. Crafting a new spell would be just like writing a new method.